# PHP Extract Direct Video Path From Openload.co Embedded URL

Tags: php, curl, hyperlink

I'm searching solution for this problem for a long time. about 3 weeks i didn't got any solutions.

See

This is the openload embedded url to be extracted

https://openload.co/embed/nLFGFH8VuZs/

The Direct Link :
https://1fiafzt.oloadcdn.net/dl/l/5qcL-TC0FIr7GgUX/nLFGFH8VuZs/VELMA2017RIPN15.mkv.mp4

Can anybody can suggest to solution to extract it. I got the direct url using the google chrome Inspect element.
I can see once i click play. How i can get using PHP or any other

Thanks

Comment: try phantomjs or youtube-dl

Answer (score 1):

Try 
openload api ( Link - 
https://openload.co/api )

First you need to generate an authenticated ticket using this url

https://api.openload.co/1/file/dlticket?file={file}&login={login}&key={key}

where , file = nLFGFH8VuZs ( in your case )

You will get ticket in JSON format

Second, to generate download link using below url -

https://api.openload.co/1/file/dl?file={file}&ticket={ticket}

You will get the download link in JSON file

(eg) url : " https://1fiafzt.oloadcdn.net/dl/l/5qcL-TC0FIr7GgUX/nLFGFH8VuZs/VELMA2017RIPN15.mkv.mp4"

Answer (score 0):

you dont need that!

Just change /embed/ to /f/ and then download it with the download butten on openload

embed:https://openload.co/embed/nLFGFH8VuZs/
non-embed:https://openload.co/f/nLFGFH8VuZs/